# UI5 application image giving 404 after deployment in launchpad

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm totally new to SAP UI5 and I'm keeping an image at images/ folder
It's working fine in all environments but it's not showing up while opening from launchpad url.

Any clues. ?

Tried setting as below in index.html

`data-sap-ui-resourceroots={ "sap.ui.demo.walkthrough": "./" }`

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/66016529/5846045 help?

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error. It usually happens when SAPUI5 cannot resolve the URI in a deployed enviroment. (thus, getting 404 makes sense).

Try resolving your URI using this method.

**Example.controller.js**

```
that.getOwnerComponent().getManifestObject().resolveUri("relative/route/from/manifest.png")
```

Then, you can set up your image URI in a model and bind it to your view wherever you want. (oIcono is my image URI)

```
let oAuxModel = new JSONModel();
let oAuxObject = {
    oIcono: oIcono
};
```

**View1.xml**

```
<GenericTile ... headerImage="{TileModel>/oIcono}">
```