# Calling formatter with parts and static value doesn't work

Tags: sapui5

Basically I want to use a formatter function to fill the 3 properties of an `sap.m.ObjectStatus` (`text`, `state`, `icon`) depending on some static value.

```xml
<m:ObjectStatus
  text="{
    parts: [
      { path: 'currentRoles>STATE_TEXT' },
      { path: 'currentRoles>STATE' },
      { path: 'currentRoles>REFERENCED_ENTRY/SV_RH_ROLE_ACTIVE' },
      { path: 'currentRoles>invalid' },
      { value: 'text' }
    ],
    formatter: '.formatter.Formatter.convertRoleStatus'
  }"
  ...
/>
```

The strange thing is; if I omit the `value` part in the XML, the function is called. If it's included, the function gets never called in the first place.

As of the one of the answers to the post [Pass Static Value to Formatter Parameters in XML View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37317223/pass-static-value-to-formatter-parameters-in-xml-view/53609552#53609552), passing parameters with `value` should work if the UI5 version is higher than 1.61. We use 1.71.2.

At other places in code, this works.

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** The issue is fixed now with [commit: `4a9cf89`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2916) which will be available in 1.80+.
Now static bindings can be used even without any  workarounds like the one mentioned below.

---

**Original answer (workaround):**

The issue is now reported in https://github.com/SAP/openui5/issues/2916. Thanks for making us aware of it!

A quick "fix" (I'd say a *monkey patch*) is to add `model: 'myExistingModel'` to the static binding info:

```json
parts: [
  { path: 'currentRoles>STATE_TEXT' },
  { path: 'currentRoles>STATE' },
  { path: 'currentRoles>REFERENCED_ENTRY/SV_RH_ROLE_ACTIVE' },
  { path: 'currentRoles>invalid' },
  { value: 'text', model: 'currentRoles' }
],
```

This fix actually doesn't make sense since static bindings don't have any models, but can be used until the official fix arrives without the need to refactor a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect there is a limitation (possibly a bug):

If you do not use a named model this works for me:

... 
`??="{ parts : [ {path: 'a'}, {path: 'b'}, {path: 'c'}, {path: 'd'}, {value: 23} ], formatter: '.myFormatter'}"`

...

```
let model = new JSONModel(this.getData());
this.getView().setModel(model);
```

...

```
myFormatter: function (a, b, c, d, v) {
  console.log(a, b, c, d, v);
},
getData: function(){
  return {"testdata": [
    { a: 1, b: "stringB", c: "stringC", d: "stringD"},
    ]};
  }
```

console output: `1 "stringB" "stringC" "stringD" 23`

The moment I name my model this stops working.
For now, if possible, use the default model for your data - not ideal?!

Try (you may have to do some model name trading?!) after assigning the named model as the default (un-named) model:

```
parts: [
            {path: 'STATE_TEXT'},
            {path: 'STATE'},
            {path: 'REFERENCED_ENTRY/SV_RH_ROLE_ACTIVE'},
            {path: 'invalid'},
            {value: 'text'}
        ],
```

while this gets it to work you may want to raise this with the UI5 Team?

Comment: Sadly the default model is already taken. None the less, thanks for the suggestion because this lifts my confusion.

Comment: Possible fix for now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61891921/5846045

Answer (score 0):

As for now, since changing the binding to a default one like Bernard propsed was not possible without heavy refactoring, I changed my formatter logic a bit in a way such as to create 3 seperat functions (with 4 parameters) that call the orginal convertRoleStatus function, each with different inputs for the fifth parameter, which is mode.
I will report the problem with SAP to hopfully resolve it someday.